# How to get a day based on a number from 1 to 365

Tags: python

I want to get a day based on a number from 1 to 365. An integer in the range of 1 to 365 is given and I need to find the day of the week for a given day in a year (starting with Sunday).

```
a = int(input())  # Integer from 1 to 365
print( # day )
```

Example: input `1`, output `4`

Comment: Stack overflow is not a general discussion type forum. It's intended to be used for very specific questions. The subject should make it very clear what exactly the question will be about and the question should include things like examples of what you have tried and a specific question. There are other forums that are better suited for discussion and coaching. Consider reviewing: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to understand what sorts of questions we're looking for here.

Comment: You might want to research the modulus operator

Comment: Every day of the year is numbered: January 1st is 1, January 2nd is 2, ..., January 31 is 31, February 1st is 32, etc. Each day of the week is also numbered: Sunday is 0, Monday is 1, etc. The problem is to figure out which day of the week the Kth day of the year is. On an input of 1 (January 1st), return 4 (Thursday); on 2 (January 2), return 5 (Friday); on 32 (February 1), return 0 (Sunday). The trick is to walk through the calendar (in some way) to pair each day of the year with its day of the week.

Comment: The first step might be to try uncommenting the sample lines given to you so you can see what they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
day_number = int(input("What day do you want to get: "))
day = days[day_number % 7]
print(f"Your day: {day}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what they want you to solve:
It is known that the first day of the year is a Thursday, if they were to give you another day of the year, you have to find what day of the week it is.

For example, if they ask you what day of the week it is on day 2 (of the year), then you would say it is a Friday (since day 1 is a Thursday).

But instead of answering "Friday", you would output the number 5, since that number corresponds to Friday.

> 0 - Sunday, 1 - Monday, 2 - Tuesday, 3 - Wednesday, 4 - Thursday , 5 - Friday, 6 - Saturday

The solution only requires some simple math - see if you can figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

The question i suppose is asking for the index assigned to the days given initially respective to the Kth day given.

A simple direct algorithm here would be to note that a day gets repeated after 7 days,i.e, 1 week. So finding the modulo of K-1 with 7 would give you the offset with respective to the first day that is a thursday. Adding that to that day would give you the day which would represent the Kth day and return the appropriate index according to that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to give you the code.
The trick here is use something called a modulo.
It's like a remainder. Eg, `10 modulo 7` -> 7 goes into 10 only one time and there is a remainder of 3, so 10 modulo 7 = 3. The symbol for modulo is a percentage sign `%`

So every time you get to the 8th day, you want to start back at the beginning. Eg:

```
0 -> 0
1 -> 1
2 -> 2
3 -> 3
4 -> 4
5 -> 5
6 -> 6
7 -> 0 <--- 7 % 7 = 0, eg 7 goes into 7 only once and with no remainders
8 -> 1
9 -> 2
etc
```